# Raspberry Pi GPIO Virtualization possible?

Tags: gpio, emulation, c++

So I have (planned) a project that utilize the GPIO. From what I know GPIO can be programmed and sending or receiving digital I/O.

But since I don't have enough fund (yet) I need to know is there any software solution where we can try to program RPi GPIO's in virtual environment? And if it is programming language specific it is for C++ or even C# ?